# Call from app to phone (web), app. with multi linked numbers

Tags: vonage

My use case is to be able to make a call from web interface to any number.
It all seams to work fine.

get `jwt` > login and get app. instance from `ConversationClient` > make a call using `app.callPhone(number)` > GET request to `answer_url`.

And this is where I stuck, it works if I will hardcode one of the linked numbers, like:

```js
return [{
      action: 'connect',
      from: 'number',
      endpoint: [{
        type: 'phone',
        number: query.to
      }]
    }]
```

but how I can pass `query.from`? or somehow decide on client side from which number I want to call?

Because each app can be linked to many numbers, and I don't want to create an app per number, but don't see any other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe at the moment the client only supports sending a single string from the browser to the application, which you're using for `to` but as MrO hinted you can pass anything as an identifier here. I would suggest putting the to and from in the string separated by a comma eg: `12125551212,14155551000` and the splitting that in your `answerUrl` handler.